# Encriptacion AES en PASCAL con INNO SETUP

Tags: pascal, inno-setup

Encriptación *AES* en PASCAL con INNO SETUP. ¿Alguna forma de implementación o consejo? Gracias.

Tengo este código, que genera una clave aleatoria, necesito guardar esa clave encriptada con AES, en una BD.

Codigo:

```
const 
  CHARS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
var
EditToCopy: TNewEdit;

procedure ButtonGenerar(Sender: TObject);
var k, j, c: Integer;
rnd : String;

begin

    rnd:='';
    for k :=1 to 1 do
    begin
      for j:=1 to 8 do
      begin
       c := Random(36)+1;
       case c of
       15: rnd := rnd + CHARS[c] + CHARS[c+1];
       1..14: rnd := rnd + CHARS[c];
        else rnd := rnd +  CHARS[c+1];
      end;
    end;
    //result := rnd;
    EditToCopy.Text := rnd;
end;

 end;
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  ButtonGenerar: TNewButton;
  WizardPage: TWizardPage;
begin
  WizardPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Ejemplo', 'Generar');
  EditToCopy := TNewEdit.Create(WizardForm);
  EditToCopy.Parent := WizardPage.Surface;
  EditToCopy.Text := '';

  ButtonGenerar := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  ButtonGenerar.Parent := WizardPage.Surface;
  ButtonGenerar.Caption := 'Generar';
  ButtonGenerar.Top := EditToCopy.Top + EditToCopy.Height + 8;
  ButtonGenerar.OnClick := @ButtonGenerar;
 end;
```

Comment: No comprendo tu pregunta. Por favor lee [ask], luego edita tu pregunta y añade suficiente detalle para explicar qué es lo que buscas y los problemas/errores que tienes para lograrlo.

Comment: Por favor comparte lo que has intentado para entender mejor tu problema

Comment: Perdón, Ya agregue codigo que utilizo para generarla, y lo que requiere. lo siento soy nuevo en StackOverflow

Comment: Sobre la parte de _encriptar_, me temo que no hay soporte directo en inno-setup para ello y la verdad, no recomendaría escribir todo el algoritmo de encriptación en el _script_ del setup. Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar una dll que implemente el algoritmo, o hacer tu mismo una (por ejemplo con Delphi) e invocar la función para encriptar desde el script del setup.

Comment: Sobre almacenar en una base de datos, generalmente puede hacerse, pero _una base de datos_ es demasiado general para poder responder esa pregunta con algún ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias @jachguate , intentare hacerlo con una dll, y les platico que tal va. Gracias!!!!